# Example of bijection from $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

What would be an example of bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$.

<strike>I can think of one: $x \mapsto (x,x+1)$ Does this work?</strike> I am not sure.<

Comment: Is it surjective?

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Oh sorry. I think it isn't. Because the point $(3,5)$ doesn't have a preimage at all. Thanks. Foolish on my behalf

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is countable and a finite Cartesian product of countable sets is itself countable, there exist 2 bijections:

$$ f: \mathbb Q \rightarrow \mathbb N$$
$$ g: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$$

And the composition $g \circ f$ will yield a bijection from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$

I will leave finding an explicit formula for f and g to you.